# SCALA Lift - Call javascript with params from Comet actor

Tags: scala, lift

I'm trying to get a comet class to call some javascript with params but can't seem to find the right way to go about it.

So far I have:

```
case class StreamItem(name: String, path: String, level: String)

class StreamComet extends CometActor with CometListener {

    private var streams: List[StreamItem] = Nil 

    def registerWith = StreamServer

    override def lowPriority = {

        case v: List[StreamItem] => streams = v; reRender()

    }

    def render = {

        "li *" #> streams.map(stream =>

            ".name *" #> stream.name &
            ".stream [id]" #> stream.path.toString

        )

    }

}


object StreamServer extends LiftActor with ListenerManager {

    private var streams: List[StreamItem] = Nil

    def createUpdate = streams

    override def lowPriority = {

        case stream: String if stream.length > 0 =>

            streams :+= StreamItem("James", stream, "_1");
            updateListeners()

    }

}
```

What I need to do now is call a javascript function, already defined, with the newly added stream. So when the ajax form is submitted and the value sent to the StreamServer, somewhere in the StreamComet render method I need to call the javascript function with that particular item in the streams list as to update the DOM. Not sure if this is the correct way to go about it though.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
import net.liftweb.http.js.JE.JsRaw
JsRaw("myJSFunction(myParam)").cmd
```